# Can't return value from another instantiated class/method using WebORB for PHP

Tags: php, instantiation, amf, weborb

I'm trying to use WebORB for PHP.

The /weborb/ folder has been copied into my web root and I can access the console via /weborb/index.php.

I've copied my test application into /weborb/_Services/Test/Main.php. The file contents is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once '/home/user/www/MyClass.php';

class Main
{
    public function testMethod($str)
    {
        return $this->MyClass->myMethod($str);
    }
}
?>
```

The file contents of "/home/user/www/MyClass.php" is:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    public function myMethod($str)
    {
        return $str;
    }
}

$MyClass = new MyClass();
?>
```

When I try to pass a string via the console is just says "Channel disconnected". There's nothing being logged into the error_log either. If I replace:

```
return $this->MyClass->myMethod($str);
```

..with..

```
return $str;
```

..it works! I simply want to be able to call other instantiated classes/methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are not declaring nor instantiating `MyClass` in your `Main` class

Try this, it should work.

```
<?php

require_once '/home/user/www/MyClass.php';

class Main {

    /**
     * 
     * @var MyClass
     */
    protected $_myClass = null;

    /**
     * Default Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_myClass = new MyClass();
    }

    /**
     * Test Method
     *
     * @param string $str
     * @return string
     */
    public function testMethod($str) {
        return $this->_myClass->myMethod($str);
    }

}

?>
```

In your MyClass.php file you do not need to create variable $MyClass, it is useless. It will be out of the scope for any other script. Just define the class and that is it, then use this class to create new objects, like in example above.

```
<?php

//  MyClass.php
// 
//  ONLY Class Definition!!!
//
class MyClass {

    public function myMethod($str) {
        return $str;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: I see where I went wrong now!! Thanks very much, that worked! :D